# Without calling recompose, How to update a particular ui component in jetpack?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In my UI, I have a circular progress bar where progress updates every second.
Other texts in that UI stays (Static). I want to update only the progress bar, instead of recomposing entire screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change the state that the progress bar depends on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to split the screen into different composables so that when a state value changes, all the views that depend on that state are grouped into a single composable.

Take a look at this code for an example:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
) {
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var otherStateValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Box {
        SomeTextView(otherStateValue)
        ProgressView(progress)
    }
}


@Composable
fun SomeTextView(text: String) {
    
}

@Composable
fun ProgressView(progress: Float) {

}
```

The `TestScreen` will be recomposed if any of the `progress` and `text` values change. But if `text` has not changed since the last recomposition, `SomeTextView` will be cached and will not be recomposed.

See [compose mental model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition) for more details on how recomposition works.

Also, if you build your views wisely, without using any side-effects directly in the code(check out side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) for more details) and caching calculation results with `remember`/view model/etc(check out state in compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)), then recomposition will be a very light operation.